# In Rust `map_or` and `map_or_else` method of `Option`/`Result`, what's lazy/eager evaluation?

Tags: rust, lazy-evaluation, eager-execution

I know Rust iterator (adaptors) are "lazy" since they doesn't actually do anything until we access them. To me iterators are like some sort of telescopes to peek stars, and that iterator adaptors are like adding more filters to make the telescope more "fun to use", e.g. a red glass s.t. everything would be red. Of course one see neither original nor all red distant view unless we actually grabbed the telescope and sees through it.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfb597e4b9a23620f5ba75f9bc9a3ff1)

```rust
fn main(){
    let distant_things = &[4, 2, 0, 6, 9];
    let telescope = distant_things.iter();
    let telescope_with_red_lens = distant_things.iter().map(|i| {
        print!("Here's red version of ");
        i
    });
    for i in telescope {
        println!("{i}");
    }
    for red in telescope_with_red_lens {
        println!("{red}");
    }
}
```

But I can't wrap my head around [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_or) statement in rust doc, which states that arguments passed to `Result::map_or` is eagerly evaluated, while `Result::map_or_else` is lazily evaluated; similar applies to `Option::map_or` and `Option::map_or_else`. To me if there's a difference on lazy/eager evaluation, than in the following code the (stdout) output should show some major time difference instead of all being near 1 second, in particular I'd expect `map_or` to report time near `0` when I called `experiment_laziness(Ok(()));`. I imagine since eager evaluation of `Result::map_or` on `Ok` variant, the closure is *actually called before* the thread sleeps for 1 second and joins, and hence the `Ok(_)` from `join()` is mapped to a closure which is *evaluated some time near 1 second before*, resulting elapsed time to be near zero. But the outputs are all near 1 second.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66ab1105bdcb27a36cccff5e4ad9dd95)

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn experiment_laziness(variant: Result<(), ()>) {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let variant_0 = variant.clone();
    let variant_1 = variant.clone();
    let map_or_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        if let Err(_) = variant_0 {
            panic!();
        }
    });
    let map_or_else_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        if let Err(_) = variant_1 {
            panic!();
        }
    });
    let map_or = map_or_handle
        .join()
        .map_or(start.elapsed(), |_| start.elapsed());
    let map_or_else = map_or_else_handle
        .join()
        .map_or_else(|_| start.elapsed(), |_| start.elapsed());
    report_stats("map_or", &variant, &map_or);
    report_stats("map_or_else", &variant, &map_or_else);
}

fn report_stats(method_name: &str, variant: &Result<(), ()>, t: &std::time::Duration) {
    println!(
        "Experiment {}, requested {}to panic, elapsed {:?}",
        method_name,
        match variant {
            Err(_) => "",
            Ok(_) => "NOT ",
        },
        t
    );
}

fn main() {
    experiment_laziness(Err(()));
    experiment_laziness(Ok(()));
}
```

It seems to me here they are all kinda "lazy". What exactly does it mean to be eager/lazy when it comes to `Result::map_or_else`, `Result::map_or`, and alike in `Option`? Or examples where either lazy/eager should be utilized/avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems to me here they are all kinda "lazy". What exactly does it mean to be eager/lazy when it comes to `Result::map_or_else`, `Result::map_or`, and alike in `Option`?

`map_or` takes a value, this means the "or" has to be evaluated before the method is even called, that is in `a.map_or(b, fn)` Rust has to first fully evaluate `a` and `b` before it can call `map_or`.

Because `map_or_else` takes a function however, it is able to only call said function in the "failure" case, and thus whatever is *inside* the function will be evaluated lazily, in `a.map_or_else(|| b, fn)` since "b" is wrapped in a function it only has to be evaluated if `a` is `Err`.

> Or examples where either lazy/eager should be utilized/avoided?

This is mostly a function of the fallback's complexity. If the fallback is simple value e.g.

```
a.map_or(42, fn)
```

then its evaluation being eager does not matter, because it's essentially free. However if the fallback is expensive like copying a string or performing an allocation, then you probably want to only do it if *necessary*.

[`clippy`'s heuristic](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#or_fun_call) on the subject is both simple and pretty effective: if the fallback involves a function call, then it recommends using a lazy version. It's sometimes not necessary (e.g. Rust's collections generally don't allocate on initialisation, so an eager `String::new()` or `HashMap::new()` doesn't really matter), but it doesn't hurt much either.

Comment: Ohhh so among the parameters in `map_or` and `map_or_else`, all the closures are lazy evaluated, i.e. side effects, if any, won't ever take affect if the calling `Result` is not matching `Ok`/`Err`, right?



And as for why my experiment doesn't work it's just since they are all trying to match `.join()`, and hence all sorts of evaluation of `map_or`/`map_or_else` including its parameters doesn't happen before thread is done (?)

Comment: "including its parameters doesn't happen before thread is done (?)" essentially yes, I think Rust normally evaluates things left to right and inner to outer unless precedence or special rules override that (e.g. boolean composition, statements, ..,) so I would expect it to evaluate the subject of a method call (it desugars to the left-most parameter of a UFCS) then each parameter in order. For your tests it means it waits until `join()` is fully evaluated (and thus the thread is done) before it gets to `start.elapsed()`.

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood the eagerness part of `Result::map_or`, thinking this means the closure to apply on `Ok` would be called regardless of if the evaluation of its calling `Result` is done. In hindsight this is kinda trivial, since in general one may want to do things according to the value in `Ok`, and hence a language must have some sort of evaluation order to prevent this.